# Is that 60 frames per second?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public PbsWheel(AnimatedPictureBox.AnimatedPictureBoxs[] pbs, AnimatedPictureBox.AnimatedPictureBoxs pb, int delta,Label label2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
            {

                if (delta > 0)
                {
                    pbs[i].AnimateRate += 1/60 * 1000;
```

1/60 * 1000 is 60 frames per second ?

This is how i animate the pictureBoxes the images inside. Im using timer for each picturebox:

```
public class AnimatedPictureBoxs : PictureBox
        {
            public static bool images; 
            List<string> imageFilenames;
            Timer t = new Timer();
            public AnimatedPictureBoxs()
            {
                images = false;
                AnimateRate = 100; //It's up to you, the smaller, the faster.
                t.Tick += Tick_Animate;
            }
            public int AnimateRate
            {
                get { return t.Interval; }
                set { t.Interval = value; }
            }
            public void Animate(List<string> imageFilenames)
            {
                this.imageFilenames = imageFilenames;
                t.Start();
            }
            public void StopAnimate()
            {
                t.Stop();
                i = 0;
            }
            int i;
            private void Tick_Animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (images == true)
                {
                    imageFilenames = null;
                }
                if (imageFilenames == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (i >= imageFilenames.Count)
                        {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Load(imageFilenames[i]);
                            i = (i + 1) % imageFilenames.Count;

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

The rate is set to 100 what i want to do is to display and when i move the mouse wheel up down to change the speed of the images animate by frames per second.

pbs is array of pictureBoxes.

Comment: I think that it's 0. This is integer arithmetic, and `1/60` == 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pbs[i].AnimateRate += 1/60 * 1000;
```

Now, `AnimateRate` is an integer property. It is very badly named. It is not a rate. It is a timer interval. In mathematical terms it is a period. Naming it rate makes it sound as though it will be a rate, or a frequency.

The mathematical relationship between period T and frequency f is:

```
T = 1/f
```

So, here's what you should do:

1. Rename the property as `AnimationInterval`.
2. When you need to convert a frequency (i.e. frame rate) to an interval use the formula above.

Note that you need to account for the fact that your frequencies are measured in frames per **second**, but your intervals are measured in milli-seconds. So your code should be:

```
pbs[i].AnimationInterval += 1000/60;
```

That looks very similar to what you had but there is a subtle difference. In mathematics, the formulae are identical. But in C#, the behaviour of the `/` operator depends on the types of its operands. You supply two integers and so `/` is integer division. And the result of `1/60` is zero. So your code does not modify the property.

I do think that you will need to modify your logic a little. As it stands, your raw data is an interval. But actually what you wish to control if frame rate. So I believe that you should maintain a variable that holds the frame rate. If you want to modify it, then make the modifications to the frame rate variable. And then set the interval like this:

```
pbs[i].AnimationInterval = 1000/frameRate;
```